# Why secondary calendars created with google library do not apear under My Calendars?

Tags: php, insert, google-calendar-api

Here is my code:

```
$summary="summary test";
$description="description test";
$location="Barcelona";
$timezone="Europe/Madrid";

$calendar = new Google_Service_Calendar_Calendar();
$calendar->setSummary($summary);
$calendar->setDescription($description);
$calendar->setLocation($location);
$calendar->setTimeZone($timezone);
echo "<br>1- calendari creat<br>";
$newCalendar = $service->calendars->insert($calendar);
```

When doing this I succesfully create a new calendar since I get a valid calendar object in $newCalendar and also I can pull it by listing the calendars. The problem is that I can see the calendar on the calendars interface uner "My Calendars".

To get the calendars list I use:

```
$service->calendarList->listCalendarList();
```

And I get all the calendars including the one I just created but I can't see them on "My Calendars" list.

Comment: When I tried the above code, I was able to create a secondary calendar and Also, when I send request to CalendarList: get, in the response list I can see the secondary calendar too. I didn't add the CalendarList: insert in my code. Let me know if your question is different from my understanding?

Answer (score 1):

You have created a new calendar correctly but what you have forgotten is that you need to [insert](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/insert) it into the calendar list

```
$calendarListEntry = new CalendarListEntry();
$calendarListEntry->setId("calendarId");    
$createdCalendarListEntry = $service->calendarList->insert($calendarListEntry);
```

Calendars aren't on the Calendar list until they have been added to it.  I am sure there is a good reason for this I just haven't found it yet.